# Testing styling in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component, it has 2 divs with different background colours based on the pageIndex. I want to test this component when the `pageIndex = 0` and when it is `pageIndex = 1`. The test succeed in both cases also it has to fail in the second one. What am i missing here?

```
export function FormSteps(props: FormStepsProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor:
            props.pageIndex === 0
              ? "green"
              : "red",
        }}
      >
        <span>Step 1</span>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor:
            props.pageIndex === 1
              ? "red"
              : "green",
        }}
      >
        <span>Step 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
test("Page Index is 0", () => {
  render(<FormSteps pageIndex={0} />);

  const fieldStep1 = screen.getByText(/step 1/i);
  const fieldStep2 = screen.getByText(/step 2/i);

  expect(fieldStep1).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "green"`);
  expect(fieldStep2).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "red"`);
});

test("Page Index is 1", () => {
  render(<FormSteps pageIndex={1} />);

  const fieldStep1 = screen.getByText(/step 1/i);
  const fieldStep2 = screen.getByText(/step 2/i);

  expect(fieldStep1).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "green"`);
  expect(fieldStep2).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "red"`);
});
```

Comment: You made two changes in the ternaries : pageIndex equality and reversed results

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, if `page index === 0`, then the first `div` would be `green` as you tested and second `div` should have `backgroundColor: "red"`, and for `page index === 1` would be otherwise. Here is your correct code to pass your tests:

```
test("Page Index is 0", () => {
  render(<FormSteps pageIndex={0} />);

  const fieldStep1 = screen.getByText(/step 1/i);
  const fieldStep2 = screen.getByText(/step 2/i);

  expect(fieldStep1).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "green"`);
  expect(fieldStep2).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "green"`);
});

test("Page Index is 1", () => {
  render(<FormSteps pageIndex={1} />);

  const fieldStep1 = screen.getByText(/step 1/i);
  const fieldStep2 = screen.getByText(/step 2/i);

  expect(fieldStep1).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "red"`);
  expect(fieldStep2).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "red"`);
});
```

But if you want for your second test to fail, should be like this (this is what I understand from your question, that the second test should fail):

```
test("Page Index is 1", () => {
  render(<FormSteps pageIndex={1} />);

  const fieldStep1 = screen.getByText(/step 1/i);
  const fieldStep2 = screen.getByText(/step 2/i);

  expect(fieldStep1).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "green"`);
  expect(fieldStep2).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor: "green"`);
});
```

Comment: I tried it, it always succeed even if i give it color blue :(

Comment: try to add the `debug()` command or look it in `snapshot` and see the style of the `divs`. Maybe this will give you an idea about how your divs are rendered and see exactly where is the problem